# Minimum size of regular graph with no short cycles

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, expander-graphs

For $d \geq 3$ (degree) and $r \geq 3$ (radius), say that a $d$-regular (finite, simple, non-oriented) graph $G$ is $r$-almost-tree if it contains no cycle of length $\leq 2 r$: in other words, we want our graph to look locally like a $d$-regular tree, in the sense that its restriction to any ball of radius $r$ always has exactly the (local) structure of a $d$-regular tree. Denote by $N(d, r)$ the minimum possible of vertices for a $r$-almost-tree $d$-regular graph. What can one tell about $N(d, r)$?

A first observation is that $N(d, r)$ is always finite. [Proof: For $n$ large, consider $d$ random involutions without fixed point of $\mathfrak{S}_{2 n}$; then the Cayley graph of the subgroup that they generate will be $r$-almost-tree with a probability tending to $1$ as $n \to \infty$]. But what about sharp upper bounds? In particular, a trivial lower bound on $N(d, r)$ is given by the size of a ball of radius $d$ in a tree, i.e. $1 + d + (d - 1) d + \cdots + (d - 1)^{r - 1} d =: N_0(d, r)$. In view of this, two natural questions are the following:

- In which cases does one have $N(d, r) = N_0(d, r)$? In particular, for fixed $d$, are there intinitely many $r$'s such that $N(d, r) = N_0(d, r)$? (Note: I investigated the case $d = 3$: then $r = 1$ and $r = 2$ fit, but not $r = 3$ nor $r = 4$).
- For fixed $d$, is the ratio $N(d, r) / N_0(d, r)$ bounded as $r$ tends to infinity?…

Comment: The answer to your first question is the [Hoffman-Singleton Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_graph), and the second question, I believe, is largely open. The best constructions known now has $N(d,r)/N_0(d,r)$ exponential in $r$.

Comment: Just a few more links that may be helpful:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_diameter_problem

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_the_largest_known_graphs_of_a_given_diameter_and_maximal_degree

https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS14

Comment: Many thanks @LeechLattice and LouisD for your links :-D And sorry for having asked a question about something which was actually classical: I had done a preliminary research over the web before asking on MO; but, as I am not a specialist of these topics, I guess that I looked at the wrong keywords… :-S

Comment: The  keyword you are missing is "girth", which is the lengh of a shortest cycle in a graph. Your quetion asks for graphs with girth greater than $2r$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem of determining the smallest regular graphs with degree $k$ and girth $g$ is normally known as the cage problem.

It has a large literature which is nicely summarised in the Dynamic Cage Survey in the Electronic Journal of Combinatorics.

https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/download/DS16/pdf/

(Apparently this is about to be updated)